# Getting Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string error

Tags: sql-server

Table is having the column as **ret_period** and contains `varchar` datatype. I'm trying to write the query for converting the datatype of column from varchar to date datatype .but it is throwing an  error as Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Can any one please let me know how to resolve this issue!
below is the sample data of column.

```
ret_period
012018
012019
012020
```

Comment: Dates have a day, month and year portion. You appear to be missing the day. What *date* is `'012020'`? 01 January 2020? 07 January 2020? 31 January 2020? Something else?

Comment: 20 years after Y2K and we repeat the mistakes? NO - just no!

Answer (score 2):

You could transform the string to a format that can be converted/casted to a DATE.

```
select *
, TRY_CAST(CONCAT(RIGHT(ret_period, 4),'-',LEFT(ret_period, 2),'-01') AS DATE) AS ret_date
from (values 
('012018'), 
('012019'), 
('012020') 
) q(ret_period)
```

Note however, that the `yyyyMMDD` format should be a safer than `yyyy-MM-DD`, since it doesn't depend on the language when casting it to a DATETIME.

Or use the `DATEFROMPARTS` function

```
select *
, DATEFROMPARTS(RIGHT(ret_period, 4), LEFT(ret_period, 2), 1) AS ret_date
from (values 
('012018'), 
('012019'), 
('012020') 
) q(ret_period)
```

| ret_period | ret_date |
| --- | --- |
| 012018 | 2018-01-01 |
| 012019 | 2019-01-01 |
| 012020 | 2020-01-01 |

Comment: Don't need the dashes though (in fact I recommend against them because they can be misinterpreted with other types, so prefer to just always use a safer format of `yyyyMMdd`).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Nope, I like the dashes.

Comment: Fails if you are converting to `datetime` in quite a number of languages. Whereas `yyyyMMdd` does not.

Comment: What you like doesn’t really matter, IMHO, especially when you’re just assembling a string like this and you don’t actually see the whole string you pass to try_cast. When you’re teaching other people things I think it’s better to use a safe format that won’t screw them up if they use your code in a slightly different way. Or at least put a disclaimer that you’re using an unsafe format simply because you like it.

Comment: But this is about casting it to a DATE, not a DATETIME. F.e. `SET LANGUAGE french
SELECT CAST('2013-12-11' AS date), CAST('2013-12-11' AS datetime);`  would get a different DATETIME.  Oh well, the OP can read the comments. I'm sticking to a dashing date.